# Are there any Non-User Modified Google App Script Triggers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, triggers, google-sheets

Is there anyway to fire an onChange trigger on a Google spreadsheet when the change was made by an App Script?

For context, I've got an app that pulls metrics from Google Analytics for individual blog posts. My challenge is when there are more than 50 blog posts (each on its own row) in a spreadsheet, or if the data is slow coming back from Google Analytics API for any reason, the application exceeds the time limit. I'd like to configure the sheet so the app runs once for each blog post, and then once the data is changed on the spreadsheet, the app is triggered to run again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

its not possible to trigger the onChange/onEdit etc from script.

however you can do this:

1. use an extra column to store the last processed date per row.
2. from your time trigger check if the last modified date of the spreadsheet (from DriveApp) is after the date stored per row.

this allows the trigger to run even once a minute while consuming little quota on the simple checks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Zig! Since each Analytic API pull takes a second or so, wouldn't the modified date for most of the rows be before the last updated date for the spreadsheet? Consequently, the program would still trying to process all but a couple rows each time its triggered? Sorry if I missed something.

Comment: not clear when the data changes by script on spreadsheet. i think im not getting the whole picture.